# How to check if data does not exist in database using validation?

Tags: php, laravel, postman, laravel-api

I have my code below that checks *"if the email has already taken"*

```
public function test(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|exists:contacts,email'
    ]);
    
    // ...
    
    return response()->json(['done!'], 200);
}
```

When I tried this in Postman, I intentionally send invalid email. But the Postman returned an error.

> Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/test

Could I ask which problem do I have or is this a Postman error/bug?

---

Here the api route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('test', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@test');
});
```

Comment: i suppose you aren't sending the accept headers for json? also perhaps this should be something other than a `GET` route ... you could be in a scenario where this is redirecting back to the same URL which will fail validation and just continue this redirect loop

Comment: @lagbox I think I sent Sir. could you check it up here it is https://i.ibb.co/DRDQBm7/image.png *you could be in a scenario..* -- but in other routes when validation fails it does not return **Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a re..**

Comment: can you set `Accept` to `application/json`?

Comment: @lagbox I can't Sir. can't modify

Comment: @lagbox sir I tried to change it to **POST** method as you said above and now it works. Could answer below and put some explanation so I could accept it.

Comment: to change the `Accept` header, you need to go to the `headers tab` and change it here https://assets.postman.com/postman-docs/override-autogenerated-header.jpg, if there is nothing there, just add it. Also, changing it to post broke the loop but you still have the issue.